# String will not convert to float

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I'm trying to find the class average for a select group of data. However, my 'score' will not change from a string to a float. Please help!

#1. Helping Mr. Couch calculate his class average

```
inFile=open("Mr.Couch.py", 'r')
outFile=open("sol.txt.py", 'w')
name=inFile.readline()
score=inFile.readline()
summ=0.0
count=0
while (score!=" "):
    count=count+1
    summ=summ+float(score)
    name=inFile.readline()
    score=inFile.readline()
average=summ/count
inFile.close()
outFile.write("Class average=", average)
outFile.close()
```

The result should give the average of all the class scores.

However, I continue to end up with the error "could not convert string into float". Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? The more information you can provide about how you got to this point and exactly what you don't understand, the better your answers will be. Remember that StackOverflow is not a "do my work for me", but a "questions and answers" site.

Comment: probably because you check  " " instead of ""

Comment: Can you paste here a sample of the data from `Mr.Couch.py` file. The code seems fine. Though, @GarrGodfrey is probably right

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readline returns "" when it reaches the end of the input.

You are checking for " ". The " " has a space and does not match the empty string.

So, when converting the empty string to a float, you get an error.